# Executing ssh-keygen automatically with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keygen

I have an `lxd` container `master`, which has an IP `10.154.151.8`. I want to perform `ssh-keygen` on it, via `ssh` from my machine. That is,

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.154.151.8',username='root')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('ssh-keygen')
```

The problem that I face here is that, after the command `ssh-keygen` is given, the *location* and the *passphrase* (two times) are asked. All I normally would do is press <kbd>enter</kbd> **three times**, when in an interactive shell. But here, since I'm connected to `master` by `ssh`, I can't do so. The output is:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/rohit/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/rohit/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/rohit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
```

So I tried doing:

```
stdin.write("\n")
stdin.write("\n")
stdin.write("\n")
```

But that didn't create the `id_rsa.pub` file.

Similarly I tried:

```
stdin.write("") 
stdin.write("") 
stdin.write("")
```

But that didn't work either.

So, What am I doing wrong here?

Moreover is there any other way (using `paramiko` preferably), to generate the `id_rsa.pub` file?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to simulate user input.

Use [`-f`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#f) and [`-N`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#N) command-line switches of [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen):

```
ssh-keygen -f keyfile -N ""
```